# Gradle build is failed with error compile with project when try to configure firebase?

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Everything works fine but when I try to configure Firebase to the gradle the following error is thrown in app level gradle file. I dont't know exactly where the error occurs but error log shows the error in last line "apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' ".

```html
Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

This the code.

```html
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'


    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'io.fabric'




repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.yyy.zzz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: ""]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

  

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }


compile
    'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'compile
    'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'compile
    'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'compile
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'compile
    'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}



apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used `compile` **as a property**, but it isn't one.
You need to pass a string argument to it.

Change

```
compile
    'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'compile
    'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'compile
    'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'compile
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'compile
    'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

with

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when add firebase from Plugin in android studio => "Tool"=> "Firebase"

**Could not get unknown property 'compile' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandle**

**And Solution is:**

Please check your build.gradle file

And check text format **compile** always on new line

```
compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you added `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` in your **top level** `build.gradle`.

Your `build.gradle` look like below:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Yup added Pranay before itself. But still have the problem

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add **google-service.json** file in your projects app folder.
paste there and invalidate the project once